# Vue - access props in child component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue child component which receives data from parent through props. What I want it to set the value of "name" property like below:

```
<template>
    <input v-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name">   <!-- this does not work -->

    {{ this.productdata.name }} <!-- this works -->
    {{ name }} <!-- this DOES NOT work -->
</template>

export default {
        data() {
            return {
                name: this.productdata.name
            }
        },
        props: ['productdata'],
        methods: {
            setProductData()
            {
                this.name = this.productdata.name;
            }
        },
        mounted() {
                // because "name: this.productdata.name" doesn't work I tried to make it like below... No success.
                this.setProductData();
        },
}
```

I guess this have something to do with when Vue child component props becoming reactive. 
I have fount working solution but it's not elegant at all:

```
mounted() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setProductData();
            }, 2000);
        },
```

Any suggestions how to do it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a watcher for your productData which sets your name the moment productData changes. This worked for me when I had a similar problem.
Therefore add in your export defaults

```
export defaults {
...
  watch: {  
    productdata: function () {
      this.setProductData()
    }  
  },
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change hook `mounted` to [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#created)

```
created() {
            this.setProductData();
        }
```

Also you can use [Computed Properties and Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

```
computed: {
    name: function () {
      return this.productdata ? this.productdata.name : '';
    }
  }
```